# Storing C++ lambdas as binary data

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm currently attempting to extend sqrat (squirrel binding utility) to cater for binding lambdas to squirrel.

The issue I've got is that although the storing and recalling code can know about the lambda's signature (Here is the code to set up the function that will execute the lambda)

```
// Arg Count 0
template <class R, class Args, class Arity>
SQFUNCTION SqMemberLambdaFuncDetail(R result, 
                                    Args args,
                                    boost::mpl::integral_c<unsigned int, 1> arity)
{
    return &SqLambda<R>::template Func0<false>;
}

// Arg Count 1
template <class R, class Args, class Arity>
SQFUNCTION SqMemberLambdaFuncDetail(R result, 
                                    Args args, 
                                    boost::mpl::integral_c<unsigned int, 2> arity)
{
    return &SqLambda<R>::template Func1<boost::mpl::at_c<Args, 1>::type, 2, false>;
}

template <class F>
SQFUNCTION SqMemberLambdaFunc(F f)
{
    typedef boost::function_types::result_type<decltype(&F::operator())>::type result_t;
    typedef boost::function_types::function_arity< decltype(&F::operator())> arity_t;
    typedef boost::function_types::parameter_types< decltype(&F::operator())>::type args_t;
    result_t result;
    args_t args;
    arity_t arity;
    return SqMemberLambdaFuncDetail<result_t, args_t, arity_t>(result, args, arity);
}
```

The lambda itself needs to be stored in an anonymous form, as binary data, and I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: I didn't understand all of it, but essentially you want to serialize the captured values? Or the whole function? What's about references etc.?

Comment: Does the serialized version of the lambda need to be deserialized after the current instance of the current program has exited?

Comment: Could you extend on how actually you'd use this? I don't see why you'd need to serialize lambdas when all you want is creating a language binding ...?

Comment: What do you mean as "binary data"  Do you need to write it to disk?  Save it in a database?  Have a pointer to it?  Clone it?  Load it from disk?  Please be more precise than "binary data".  Could you solve the problem to run `print` on `bob`:  `struct bob{ int state; void print()const{ std::cout<<state<<'\n'; }; };`?

Comment: In this Squirrel binding, do you have the ability to allocate a block of memory inside the scripting system, access that block later, and so forth? That is, does this language have something like Lua's Userdata construct? If so, the it should be a matter of just using it to store the value of the lambda, then destroying it on GC cleanup.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas This is precisely what I was trying to do, squirrel also has a UserData construct (much of squirrel was directly inspired by Lua).

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are not guaranteed to be standard layout (so looking at their bits is never legal), nor are their contents introspectable.

If you want code that can be serialized and then run remotely, use a scripting engine.  There are many, and some interact well with C++.

Or just boost phoenix, which makes reflectible C++-esque code that is lambda-esque.

However if your only problem is storing a *copy* of a lambda with signature `R(Args...)` generically, simply use a `std::function<R(Args...)>`.

Comment: I am using a scripting engine, that's what squirrel is, however I need to be able to bind C++ code to it (so it can script the things that need to be scripted). I can bind global functions, and class methods already, but being able to bind lambdas would be very useful, hence my attempts to do so.

Comment: @JonHodgson You can bind global functions and class methods without storing them as binary data. Why do you think it necessary to do so when binding lambdas?

Comment: @Oktalist I think my thinking went off down a wrong path, I was concerned with the lambda going out of scope after the point at which I called the binding method, and thus being destroyed before it gets used. I see now that I'm going to have to deal with that issue differently.

Comment: @jon you can create a copy of a lambda and store it in a std function...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately C++ by design builds an impenetrable wall between code and data.

Lambda is code (plus captured data) and cannot be treated as data (e.g. stored on disk, sent over network, inspected). What C++ allows you is to treat as data **pointers to code** but not the code itself that is built only compile-time and immutable. Moreover pointers are valid only in the very same program (sending a pointer to some other program is pointless as it's meaningful only in a specific address space).

The only **portable** way out is to implement (or incorporate) a full programming language that allows the creation of custom code at run time.

Comment: Incorporating the full programming language (squirrel) is what I need this functionality for!.. but thanks for clarifying certain things for me. It's stuff I actually knew, but somehow lost track of when I was buried in template metaprogramming, so now you've brought it back into focus I can see I have to do a bit of a rethink.

Answer (score 2):

You can create LambdaWrapper class which will store lambda itself (e.g. in `boost::function` or `std::function`). It will be a normal class, so you should be able to pass it to squirrel like normal class.

Comment: This appears to have been the solution. I created a LambdaWrapperBase class (so that I could store pointers to variety of LambdaWrappers in a container), and then a templated LambdaWrapper class which inherited from it. It seems to work for some lambdas, but I have an issue if my lambda references "this", which could potentially make it more useful, though as is I can use it for quite a few things I think.

Comment: Native C++ objects which are referenced from scripting language must live as long as their counterparts in script live. Is this the issue? If not, please write what happens.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is allocate some memory within your scripting language, store a C++ object inside of it, and then access it later.

The general problems you face are:

1. Storing the object in accord with the rules of C++.
2. Getting it back.

Given some type `T`, if that type is copyable or moveable, you can always copy/move construct it into an allocation which is large enough to store `T` and is properly aligned. The code for that is pretty simple:

```
void func(T t)
{
  void *alloc = GetAllocation(sizeof(T), alignof(T));
  new(alloc) T(t);
}
```

Where `GetAllocation` is whatever you need to do to allocate memory in the script system. The placement `new` syntax will construct the object of type `T`, in this case by copying from `t`. You could move as well: `new(alloc) T(std::move(t));`.

Oh, and you will also need to do whatever gymnastics your scripting system requires so that this object will gets its destructor called once the script is finished with it. This usually involves registering some kind of function with the scripting system for that particular object. But destroying the object dips into step 2 a bit.

But that was the easy part. The hard part is receiving this data and using it again. For example, if a script tries to call this function, you're going to have to attach some hook to it that will let your code know to call it. And when that happens, it has to reconstitute the constructed value of type `T`.

The problem for you is this: you don't actually know what type `T` is.

If your function was passed a lambda, you *cannot* know what type it is. Oh, you can use `decltype` to access the type. But that's only because the registration function was passed a value of that type to begin with.

On the receiving end, from your scripting language, all you have is `void*`. And C++ has no way of recording what type you used directly.

Of course, C++ does have ways of hiding the type so that you can reconstruct it later. This is generally called type erasure: you have one type which could contain a value of numerous types, so long as they have a certain interface. And that would permit you to interact with the value without knowing its type.

`std::function` is such a type for function objects. It can take *any* type which is callable: function pointers, member pointers, functors, and lambdas (aka: functors). Since calling it is what you want, that should be an acceptable type-erased object.

So long as you know which signature each registration function will register. After all, the signature for the functions that it carries is part of the type for `std::function`. So you would have to standardize such functors to a specific signature that is known at the time that the functor is registered with the scripting system.

You can have different functions that register different signatures. Indeed, you can make such functions templates. But you still need to know at the time a specific function is registered what its signature is.

This is also important for destroying the object at GC time, since you need to be able to cast it back.

Comment: Thanks for the completeness of this answer. This is what I was originally trying to do, but I couldn't get it to work, perhaps because i was getting things wrong regarding std::function declarations (the whole thing needs to be templated to allow different signatures to be dealt with automatically at compile time). So I went down the route mentioned in my other post  (which I have now edited by the way), but as you know, ran into other issues.