# C++11 Lambda Capture Confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

For reasons associated with the circumstances I'm using them in, I declare lambdas in one object, copy them to a second object, and execute them from a static function of a third class.

It appears to work with some lambdas (i.e. no crashes and the expected data returned from the call), but not with others (they crash).

Ok, it seems my original post was a little short on information, so I've developed a simple app to demonstrate the issue.

```
// LambdaCaptureTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct LambdaWrapperBase {
    virtual ~LambdaWrapperBase() {}
};

template <typename Lambda>
struct LambdaWrapper : public LambdaWrapperBase
{
    LambdaWrapper(Lambda lambda) : lambda_(lambda) {}
    Lambda&  lambda_;
};

struct LambdaCallerBase
{
    virtual void executeLambda(LambdaWrapperBase*) = 0;
};

template <typename Lambda>
struct LambdaCaller : public LambdaCallerBase
{
    void executeLambda(LambdaWrapperBase* lambda_wrapper_base) override
    {
        typedef LambdaWrapper<Lambda> LambdaWrapper_t;
        LambdaWrapper_t* lambda_wrapper = dynamic_cast<LambdaWrapper_t*>(lambda_wrapper_base);
        std::cout << "\"" << lambda_wrapper->lambda_().c_str() << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<LambdaWrapperBase> > g_lambda_wrappers;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<LambdaCallerBase> > g_lambda_callers;

std::string g_tag = "A global Tag";

class CreateLambdas
{
public:
    CreateLambdas() : tag_("A member Tag")
    {
        auto lambda1 = []() -> std::string { return std::string("An immediate tag"); };
        addLambda(lambda1);
        auto lambda2 = []() -> std::string { return g_tag; };
        addLambda(lambda2);
        std::string tag = "A Local Tag";
        auto lambda3 = [=]() -> std::string { return tag; };
        addLambda(lambda3);
        auto lambda4 = [this]() -> std::string { return this->tag_; };
        addLambda(lambda4);

        // These all work as expected
        std::cout << "\"" << lambda1().c_str() << "\"" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\"" << lambda2().c_str() << "\"" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\"" << lambda3().c_str() << "\"" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\"" << lambda4().c_str() << "\"" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class F> void addLambda(F method)
    {
        g_lambda_wrappers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<LambdaWrapperBase>(new LambdaWrapper<F>(method)));      
        g_lambda_callers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<LambdaCallerBase>(new LambdaCaller<F>()));
    }

    std::string tag_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CreateLambdas createLambdas;
    // This outputs "An immediate tag"
    g_lambda_callers[0]->executeLambda(g_lambda_wrappers[0].get()); 

    // This outputs "A global tag"
    g_lambda_callers[1]->executeLambda(g_lambda_wrappers[1].get()); 


    // this crashes. If I look at that point in the debugger, 
    // then the local variable "tag" says "Error reading characters of string"        
    g_lambda_callers[2]->executeLambda(g_lambda_wrappers[2].get()); 

    // this crashes. If I look at it in the debugger at the crash point,
    // then "this" is 0xcccccccc - i.e. invalid        
    g_lambda_callers[3]->executeLambda(g_lambda_wrappers[3].get()); 
    return 0;
}
```

Edit :

So Yakk pointed out that I'd made a mistake by storing the lambda as a reference in the wrapper class, rather than a copy, so thanks very much for that Yakk, changing that class definition to this results in a successful run

```
template <typename Lambda>
struct LambdaWrapper : public LambdaWrapperBase
{
    LambdaWrapper(Lambda lambda) : lambda_(lambda) {}
    Lambda lambda_;
};
```

So that's fixed my issue, many thanks to Yakk,

Further Edit:

DOH! Scratch my last additional question, forgot about another reference!

Comment: The code you are claiming to run is not the code you are running.

Comment: "*this doesn't work*" With what? You haven't shown us the code where the problem is actually taking place. Is this in reference to your previous question about [storing lambdas in a scripting language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37896707/734069)? If so, then your storage and retrieval code is probably to blame.

Comment: @Yakk,  actually that is the code I'm running, it's just that's it's only one part of it, where the lambda is actually defined (I'm only using one of those definitions at one time of course). I thought that it would be easy enough to deduce the full context from the rest of my description, so I just gave examples of the sorts of lambdas which are executing correctly, and the ones that aren't. I will extend my question to try to clarify things.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, you may well be right. But as I said, the storage and retrieval code works correctly for the first two lambda declarations, so at this point I was simply asking if captures are expected to be lost when lambdas are copied.

Comment: @JonHodgson: "*But as I said, the storage and retrieval code works correctly for the first two lambda declarations*" No, you simply didn't get a crash. That doesn't mean it was working; you just got lucky. As for your last sentence, if lambda captures were lost on copying, why would lambdas be copyable *at all*? That seems like a pretty serious hole in the language, right?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas.. ok, perhaps you prefer "appears to work as I  expected"? I.e. no crashes, and the correct value returned when the lambda is called. I'm currently working on trying to set up something complete I can post here. And yes, it wouls seem like a pretty serious hole.. unless there were some syntactical faux pas I was making.

Comment: @Jon you are storing a reference in the wrapper.  The lamba is not stored in the wrapper.  With no lambda storage, having wrapper outlive the lambda that wrapped them results in rapid UB.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks! That's it! I should have thought of that.. . but something still has me a little confused, see my follow up

Comment: @JonHodgson Examine the lifetime of the lamba.  Walk through each step.  What happens when you call `addLambda`?  Distinguish between moves, copies and references.  But really, *stop holding references in your wrapper*.  Use pointers, and make the take-address-of obvious: when you do that, look *at the variable right there* and determine its lifetime.  Or *use values*, which is probably the right way to go.

Comment: @Yakk, thanks. I'd spotted my idiocy before I read last comment That last bit was an experiment to check I was understanding things properly, rather than an intention to keep using references... and I had understood them, just made a silly mistake and overlooked the passing by value into addLambda. Then again, in my defence, it is 5 am here, so I should probably get some sleep :)